# Load only webpage on logon

Tags: linux, login, window-manager, web

I would like to know if it's possible to **load only 1 web page when Linux logs on with an automatic user**. This server will be used **only to display information, no interaction is required** and even if the end user wants to interact with the X window / Window Manager (opening another window, running other apps, switching users, switching to Virtual consoles), he'll not be able to do (the Window manager will not let him).

I don't have in mind a specific Linux distribution or window manager, but more looking to see first if it's possible or not.

I looked on the Internet (Window managers, X window, embedded Linux), but I didn't find anything useful for my case

Don't hesitate to contact me if you need more clarification regarding my need.

Comment: This setup is usually called "information kiosk", "web kiosk" or even just "kiosk". I haven't set anything like it up, so I can't provide a real answer. These can be useful search terms, though.